# How to efficiently join records with separate string table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, join

I have a large table with a lot of duplicate string data. To save space, I have moved the string data to a separate table. My tables now look something like this:

```
MyRecords
RecordId (int) | FieldA (int) | FieldB (datetime) | FieldC (...) | MyString1Id (int) | MyString2Id (int) | MyString3Id (int) | ...

MyStrings
StringId (int) | StringValue (varchar)
```

The `MyRecords` table has about 10 foreign keys to the string table. I have a stored procedure `GetMyRecords` that retrieves a list of records with the actual string values. This sp now has 10 joins to the string table for each string relation:

```
SELECT [Field1], [Field2], [Field3], ..., [Strings1].[StringValue], [Strings2].[StringValue], ...
 FROM MyRecords INNER JOIN
   MyStrings AS Strings1 ON MyRecords.MyString1Id = Strings1.StringId INNER JOIN
   MyStrings AS Strings2 ON MyRecords.MyString2Id = Strings2.StringId INNER JOIN
   MyStrings AS Strings3 ON MyRecords.MyString3Id = Strings3.StringId INNER JOIN
            (more joins)
    WHERE [Field1] = @Field1 AND [Field2] = @Field2
```

`GetMyRecords` is considerably slower than I would want because of all the joins. How could I improve performance for this sp?  Can I somehow turn this into a single join?

The strings table has a clustered primary key on `StringId`, and all the where fields are in a nonclustered index on the `MyRecords` table.

Comment: You really should normalize your structure though...this is not really extensible and will be brutal to maintain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I somehow turn this into a single join?

If it is common for the same *combination* of strings to occur on multiple rows of `MyRecords` then it would make sense to store those combinations in a separate table. Then you could do a single join.

So long as you are only storing individual strings, then it is not possible to do this in a single join, since it has to search for each string separately.

You can make the queries easier to read and write by creating a view of the table that includes all of the joins. This will not improve performance, but it will make your queries look a lot better.

> How could I improve performance for this sp?

There are things you can do, depending on the form of the data.

If the strings in one field contains (mostly) different information than another field, then you could try putting them into different tables. There is a chance this could improve performance if the maximum length of one field is much smaller than the other or if the number of different values for one field is much smaller than the other.

Answer (score 4):

You should probably take one further step toward normalization and create a join table.  Instead of having the `MyStringNId` columns in `MyRecords`, have a third table:

```
CREATE TABLE RecordsStrings (
    RecordId [theDataType] NOT NULL REFERENCES MyRecords (RecordId),
    StringId [theDataType] NOT NULL REFERENCES MyStrings (StringId)
)
```

It is not convenient then to have all the strings in the same row of the returned data from the `SELECT` (though maybe there's a way to do this with a pivot somehow), so it's probably better to restructure the calling code to deal with results returned from:

```
SELECT [StringValue]
FROM   [MyStrings] s
INNER JOIN [RecordsStrings] rs ON rs.StringId = s.StringId
INNER JOIN [MyRecords] r ON rs.RecordId = r.RecordId
WHERE  r.Field1 = @Field1 AND r.Field2 = @Field2
```

If you need the other fields from `MyRecords`, you can select those as well, though they would appear in every relevant row.  If you have multiple matches on Field1 and Field2, though, that may be helpful.

Comment: Good answer. I was frustrated by the Many-to-Many problem until it was explaind to me. Best db book I ever bought "Database Design For Mere Mortals" by Michael J. Hernandez. ISBN: 0-201-69471-9

Comment: Normalization doesn't seem possible. How would I know which string goes with which column? I would have to add another column to the join table.

Comment: @Jappie If it matters which column goes with which string, that is true.  I made the (apparently poor) assumption that the order of the strings was irrelevant.  For performance, then, it would probably be better to add a column to the join table as you suggest rather than suffer through the multiple joins as the query in your original question has.

Answer (score 1):

First step would be to run a performance analysis to see where the problems are.

Just on a lark though, you can pick up a bit of a performance gain by using (nolock) on the joined tables.